# Represent a radial dendrogram in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to represent a dendrogram in radial lines with arcs.

So far,I have tried

```
t2=linkage(squareform(t1),'single')
dendrogram(t2,0,'colorthreshold',0.5)
```

and got the output as [image: http://i48.tinypic.com/1zpgnyq.jpg]

Could you please let me know how to represent the same as a radial dendrogram in MATLAB, as in the image below.

[image: http://i45.tinypic.com/ebaag2.png]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try my Polar Dendrogram function from MATLAB Central: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21983-draw-a-polar-dendrogram

Hope it works for you!

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried the polar dendrogram function.
[IMG]http://i45.tinypic.com/14nftax.png[/IMG]
I also need to represent the colors as in the above radial dendrogram image. Also could you please let me know how to change the labels in the dendrogram.
Thank you once again.

Comment: My polar dendrogram function is a simple wrapper around the built in dendrogram function, taking exactly the same inputs and providing the same capabilities for managing the colors and labels in the plot - which are unfortunately a bit limited. You can learn exactly what you can do on the documentation page for the dendrogram command. If you need more control, I'm afraid you'll need to either dig into the dendrogram command and modify it (don't be afraid, it's not that complex - but take a copy of the existing version first) - or get the handles of the tree as an output and manually prettify.

Comment: Yeah I am trying to get a workaround by using dendrogram function for changing the labels.

Answer (score 2):

Matlab does not have a built in function for making a radial dendrogram. A quick search turned up [a page about Hierarchical Random Graphs](http://tuvalu.santafe.edu/~aaronc/hierarchy/) with code that may work for you.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to use this for my data.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the Matlab code provided by @Sam Roberts and have attached the diff of the files:

```
1c1
< function [h,T,perm] = polardendrogram(Z,varargin)
---
> function [h,T,perm] = polardendrogram(Z, labels, varargin)
47,48c47,49
<     [x,y]=pol2cart((((i-minx)/xrange)*(pi*11/6))+(pi*1/12),1.1);
<     text(x,y,num2str(perm(i)));
---
>     [x,y]=pol2cart((((i-minx)/xrange)*(pi*11/6))+(pi*1/12),1.01);
>     THETA = (((i-minx)/xrange)*330 + 15); % pi/12 = 15° 
>     text(x,y,labels(perm(i)), 'rotation', THETA);
```

As you can see, this requires to specify the labels before the arguments you would typically pass to the Matlab in-built dendrogram() function on which polardendrogram() is based.

There is likely a cleaner way to do this but this one works for me.

If you have comments on this, please let me know.